# Android: Unable to flip

Tags: android, imageview, flip

I have coded an application whereby when users tap on an ImageView, it will flip to the other side. At start, imgFront will be shown. Upon tap by user, imgBack should be shown on the same axis as imgFront. However, it does not happens but my application is able to run smoothly. Any ideas on what is the issue?

Java:

```
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView imgFront;
ImageView imgBack;
ImageView imageView3;
ImageView imageView4;

boolean isBackVisible = false; // Boolean variable to check if the back image is visible currently

AnimatorSet setRightOut;
AnimatorSet setLeftIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRightOut = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.flight_right_out);
    setLeftIn = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), R.animator.flight_left_in);

    imgFront = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFront);
    imgFront.setOnClickListener(this);

    imgBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
    imgBack.setOnClickListener(this);

    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView3.setOnClickListener(this);

    imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView4.setOnClickListener(this);





}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgFront:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(this.imgFront);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(this.imgBack);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(this.imgBack);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(this.imgFront);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.imageView3:
            if (!isBackVisible) {
                setRightOut.setTarget(this.imageView3);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(this.imageView4);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = true;
            } else {
                setRightOut.setTarget(this.imageView4);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(this.imageView3);
                setRightOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
                isBackVisible = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:clickable="false">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFront"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/front"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgBack"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgFront"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBack"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgBack"
        android:clickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:clickable="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/front"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgFront3"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="imgBack3"
        android:clickable="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice effort for that code, but please have a look at my library just developed [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView) that includes basic flip animation and extends `ViewFlipper`. I mean a fully customizable library where you will be able to swap any kind of views and layouts with any kind of animation and shapes you desire (and much more), included the Gmail image flipping.